# Dismiss Slide Menu by Clicking Anywhere in ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I have MainViewController which has a hamburger menu button to open slide menu

How can i dismiss the slide menu when user clicks anywhere in MainViewController

Now i can only dismiss the menu by pressing the button again

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It might help

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
         super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
         //retract menu
}
```

Comment: this func should be implemented in menu class or main view controller ?